# Restrict users from changing rows inserted 3 hours ago in mysql

Tags: mysql

I inserted a number of rows 3 hours ago and I don't want these rows to change. How can I write a sql statement that will compare current time with the timestamp in the row and restrict users from changing it if above criteria is met.

Thanks

Comment: You asked the wrong question: you can write a SQL statement that will prevent such an update, but the next guy won't and you'll be left with what you want to be a database invariant (rows older than 3 hours are immutable) which varies. There are answers below which answer the question you asked, they won't maintain your invariant though.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it by using mysql, you will have to use the `INTERVAL` statement which will allow you to "add" time to date functions... for instance:

```
UPDATE table
SET data = 'whatever'
WHERE NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR  < last_change
```

You can find more info and examples here: [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: I think there is some mistake in query? Shouldn't it be Now() - Interval 3 HOUR?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a WHERE clause in all updates:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET foo = bar
WHERE inserttime > NOW() - interval 3 hour
```